# Word clustering with gensim

Tags: python, neural-network, cluster-analysis, gensim, lda

I'm new to gensim, I was reading about [Experiments on the English Wikipedia](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation) and from what I understand, it creates a model with topics and words and tries to relate them.

On my company, we have a list of phrases that we cluster manually after filtering them with a script that uses the Damerau-Levenshtein distance formula (actually, this data is on Elasticsearch and we use the fuzzyness search and the score to understand if the matching should be considered).

Example:

`PHP Developer` is in the cluster `Developer`.

Let's say there is `Java Developer`, this too should be clustered as `Developer`.

The fuzzy search of Elasticsearch matches `Java Developer` to be similar to `PHP Developer` (Elasticsearch uses the Damerau-Levenshtein distance formula) so the script considers to put the same clusters of `PHP Developer` that are already validated (this validation is done manually).

My question is: can this gensim be useful to cluster words using Wikipedia's database as a "dictionary"?

I also find this [pre-trained vectors](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/pretrained-vectors.md?utm_campaign=buffer&utm_content=buffer0df9b&utm_medium=social&utm_source=linkedin.com) done by Facebook, I don't know if I can use this for my problem.

I tried to load one of the `.txt` files with this Python script:

```
import gensim

sentences = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('/Users/genesisxyz/Downloads/wiki.it.vec')
print(sentences)

p = sentences.similarity('uomo', 'donna')
print(p)
```

This was just a first experiment I was doing, but I still don't know where to start, I did a little of neural networks on other topics not related to words semantics, but here I have no clue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, did you find any useful methods for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be confusing how gensim LDA works. The wikipedia dataset is just a large piece of text in one language. The topic model does not derive categorization from the entries in Wikipedia directly.

Also, it seems to me that you are looking for a fine-grained and not straightforward categorization where statistical approaches based on frequency of words may be not very suitable for.

Using gensim the problem that you may arrive at is that the topics generated by LDA from the text you want to cluster may be significantly different from the clusterization you do manually (e.g. few clusters aggregated into one topic, documents from one cluster spread between a few topics, etc.).

You may want to check if the manually verified clusters are indeed well separable when you apply word2vec vector metrics. If they are then sure you can use pretrained vectors from FB.

Alternatively, since you have some good quality data (manually verified clusters), I would check a classifier (e.g. SVM, CRF).